# Custom Annotation Seaborn Heatmap

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn in Python to create a Heatmap. I'm able to annotate the cells with the values passed in, but I'd like to add annotations that signify what the cell means. For example, instead of merely seeing `0.000000`, I'd like to see the corresponding label, for instance "Foo," or `0.000000 (Foo)`.

The [Seaborn documentation](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap) for the heatmap function is a bit cryptic with the parameter that I believe is the key here:

```
annot_kws : dict of key, value mappings, optional
  Keyword arguments for ax.text when annot is True.
```

I tried setting `annot_kws` to a dictionary of the aliases to the values, i.e., `{'Foo' : -0.231049060187, 'Bar' : 0.000000}`, etc., but I'm getting an AttributeError.

Here is my code (I've manually created the data array here for reproducability):

```
data = np.array([[0.000000,0.000000],[-0.231049,0.000000],[-0.231049,0.000000]])
axs = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=-0.231049, vmax=0, annot=True, fmt='f', linewidths=0.25)
```

Here is the (working) output when I don't use the `annot_kws` parameter:

[image: Working output]

And here the stack trace for when I *do* include the `annot_kws` param:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-38f91f1bb4b8> in <module>()
     12 
     13 
---> 14 axs = sns.heatmap(data, vmin=min(uv), vmax=max(uv), annot=True, annot_kws=kws, linewidths=0.25)
     15 concepts

/opt/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.pyc in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, ax, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, **kwargs)
    272     if square:
    273         ax.set_aspect("equal")
--> 274     plotter.plot(ax, cbar_ax, kwargs)
    275     return ax
    276 

/opt/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.pyc in plot(self, ax, cax, kws)
    170         # Annotate the cells with the formatted values
    171         if self.annot:
--> 172             self._annotate_heatmap(ax, mesh)
    173 
    174         # Possibly add a colorbar

/opt/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.pyc in _annotate_heatmap(self, ax, mesh)
    138             val = ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val)
    139             ax.text(x, y, val, color=text_color,
--> 140                     ha="center", va="center", **self.annot_kws)
    141 
    142     def plot(self, ax, cax, kws):

/opt/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.pyc in text(self, x, y, s, fontdict, withdash, **kwargs)
    590         if fontdict is not None:
    591             t.update(fontdict)
--> 592         t.update(kwargs)
    593         self.texts.append(t)
    594         t._remove_method = lambda h: self.texts.remove(h)

/opt/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in update(self, props)
    755             func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    756             if func is None or not six.callable(func):
--> 757                 raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    758             func(v)
    759             changed = True

AttributeError: Unknown property tokenized
```

Finally, `kws`, the attribute I'm passing in the line in the stack trace, is the dictionary and it would look basically like this:

```
kws = {'Foo': -0.231049060187, 'Bar': 0.0}
```

Hope everything makes sense, and I'd appreciate any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This feature has just been added in the recent version of Seaborn 0.7.1.

> From [Seaborn update history](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/whatsnew.html):
>
> > The annot parameter of heatmap() now accepts a rectangular dataset in addition to a boolean value. If a dataset is passed, its values will be used for the annotations, while the main dataset will be used for the heatmap cell colors

Here is an example

```
data = np.array([[0.000000,0.000000],[-0.231049,0.000000],[-0.231049,0.000000]])
labels =  np.array([['A','B'],['C','D'],['E','F']])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(data, annot = labels, fmt = '')
```

Note, fmt = '' is necessary if you are using non-numeric labels, since the default value is fmt='.2g' which makes sense only for numeric values and would lead to an error for text labels.
[image]

Comment: Is there a link to formatting options somewhere? I seem not to be able to find it.

Comment: Not really, but from what I see in the [code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/matrix.py), it is used via matplotlib's `ax`:

    ax.text(x, y, ("{:" + self.fmt + "}").format(val), **text_kwargs)

If the value is an integer, you can use 'd', but that fails if the values are floats.

Comment: @SergioLucero Is it possible to add floats in this labels array ? I get an error message ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'numpy.str_'

Comment: why does the shape of annot and data needs to be the same?

Comment: fmt = '' is lifesaving

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe this is possible in the current version. If you are up to a hack-y workaround, you could do the following ...

```
# Create the 1st heatmap without labels 
sns.heatmap(data=df1, annot=False,)

# create the second heatmap, which contains the labels,
# turn the annotation on,
# and make it transparent
sns.heatmap(data=df2, annot=True, alpha=0.0)
```

Note that you may have a problem with the coloring of your text labels. Here, I created a custom `cmap` to have all labels uniformly black.

Comment: this is a nice hack!

Answer (score 9):

`aanot_kws` in Seaborn serves a different purpose, namely, it provides access to *how* annotations are displayed, rather than *what* is displayed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ata = np.array([[0.000000,0.000000],[-0.231049,0.000000],[-0.231049,0.000000]])
sns.heatmap(data, vmin=-0.231049, vmax=0, annot=True, fmt='f', annot_kws={"size": 15}, ax=ax[0])
sns.heatmap(data, vmin=-0.231049, vmax=0, annot=True, fmt='f', annot_kws={"size": 10}, ax=ax[1]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bushmanov. Do you know of any way to change the annotations? Or is it a lost cause?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Thanks for acceptance. Heatmaps are representations of values, so I strongly *believe* there are no ways intrinsic to heatmap that would allow to pull nonexistent label `Foo` from the underlying data. If you definitely need to attach a label, I would look at matplotlib how it overlays text on its plots. Afterall seaborn is matplotlib.