# How to Add Text plus Value in Python Seaborn Heatmap

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying the python Seaborn package to create a heatmap.
So far I been able to create the heatmap with the values in it.
My final line in the code for creating the heatmap is:

```
sns.heatmap(result, annot=True, fmt='.2f', cmap='RdYlGn', ax=ax)
```

The resulting image is shown below:
[image: Heatmap with Values]

However, I want to also have a string next to the values.
For example: *AAPL -1.25* instead of *-1.25* in the second field of the second row. Is there a way to add the text to the values in the heatmap?

Answer (score 14):

You can add custom annotations to your heatmap using seaborn. In principle, this is only a special case of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799642/6614295). The idea now is to add the string and numbers together to get the proper custom labels. If you have an array `strings` of the same shape as `result` that contains the respective labels you can add them together using:

```
labels = (np.asarray(["{0} {1:.3f}".format(string, value)
                      for string, value in zip(strings.flatten(),
                                               results.flatten())])
         ).reshape(3, 4)
```

Now you can use this label array as custom labels for your heatmap:

```
sns.heatmap(result, annot=labels, fmt="", cmap='RdYlGn', ax=ax)
```

If you put this together using some random input data the code will look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

results = np.random.rand(4, 3)
strings = strings = np.asarray([['a', 'b', 'c'],
                                ['d', 'e', 'f'],
                                ['g', 'h', 'i'],
                                ['j', 'k', 'l']])

labels = (np.asarray(["{0} {1:.3f}".format(string, value)
                      for string, value in zip(strings.flatten(),
                                               results.flatten())])
         ).reshape(4, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(results, annot=labels, fmt="", cmap='RdYlGn', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the strings are now correctly added to the values in the annotations.