# Heatmap drawing using matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I am new to Python. I need to draw a heat map with annotation in every grid using a data frame like this:

```
t=pd.DataFrame({'ReturnType':['ReturnWithoutReceipt','Return With Receipt',
                          'ReturnWithoutReceipt','Return With Proof Of Purchase','Return With Proof Of Purchase',
                'Return With Receipt'],
                'Payment':['Card','Cash','Cash','Cash','Card','Card'],
                'Hour':[11,12,12,14,16,16],
                'value':[1,26,3,67,17,37],
                'Label':['1.0--11','26.0--12','3.0--12','67.0--14','17.0--16','37.0--16']})
```

In my heat map, the row is ReturnType, the column is Payment. The color is decided by value. Label need to be shown in every grid. So, the figure will look like this:

[image]

So how to do it using matplotlib or seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reshape `DataFrame` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = t.set_index(['ReturnType','Payment']).unstack()
print (df)
                              Hour      value          Label          
Payment                       Card Cash  Card Cash      Card      Cash
ReturnType                                                            
Return With Proof Of Purchase   16   14    17   67  17.0--16  67.0--14
Return With Receipt             16   12    37   26  37.0--16  26.0--12
ReturnWithoutReceipt            11   12     1    3   1.0--11   3.0--12
```

Select each `DataFrame` by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) (because `MultiIndex` in columns)

```
df1 = df.xs('value', axis=1, level=0)
lab = df.xs('Label', axis=1, level=0)
print (df1)
Payment                        Card  Cash
ReturnType                               
Return With Proof Of Purchase    17    67
Return With Receipt              37    26
ReturnWithoutReceipt              1     3

print (lab)
Payment                            Card      Cash
ReturnType                                       
Return With Proof Of Purchase  17.0--16  67.0--14
Return With Receipt            37.0--16  26.0--12
ReturnWithoutReceipt            1.0--11   3.0--12
```

And last pass second `DataFrame` to parameter `annot`, idea for show labels is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799642):

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df1, annot=lab, fmt="")
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very clear. May I ask one more thing: how to put the field "Label" in every grid, given after duplication?

Comment: @FengChen - Not sure if understand `how to put the field "Label" in every grid, given after duplication`, can you explain more?

Comment: @FengChen - Do you think `ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)` ?

Comment: Hi, I use your figure to make an example in my question. Please take a look. What I want is that on every grid, there is a Label value shown on it. This is similar to annot. But I need show Label field, not value field. Hope I make myself clear.

Comment: @FengChen - Now understand, one small thing, need `sum` or `mean`?

Comment: Hi, I revise the data frame t. Now there is no duplicates in it. Please just use it.

Comment: @FengChen - So in real data no duplicates?

Comment: Yeah. now t in my question has no duplicates. So, use the value to make different colors and show Label on every grid.

Comment: OK, gime some time

Comment: really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what a heat map is. A heat map is a rectangular array of M rows by N columns where counts at some index (m, n) are represented as colors.

The shape of `'value:'` is not equal to the product of `'ReturnType:` and `'Payment:'` as per your question.