# Python Seaborn Heatmap formatting annotation

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Hi all I am trying to recreate this Seaborn Heatmap https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/heatmap_annotation.html with some of my own data which looks like:

[image: Spend By Month]

I'm finiding it hard to understand the formatting documentation and hoping to get the annotation to show eg `437521` as `$438k`. Is that possible at all? Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks @BallpointBen. I was more referring to the the actua data labels inside of the plot. but will also look into the colorbar formatting as well

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158075/custom-annotation-seaborn-heatmap

Comment: Thanks @BallpointBen. I have now managed to get the `k` & $ in on the end using `for t in ax.texts: t.set_text("$" + t.get_text() + "k")` but still trying to figure out how to round the 438521 to`438`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with add units and round:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478574/2901002
def human_format_round(number):
    units = ['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P']
    k = 1000.0
    magnitude = int(floor(log(number, k)))
    print (magnitude)
    return '{:.0f}{}'.format(round(number / k**magnitude), units[magnitude])

 for t in ax.texts: 
     t.set_text("$" + human_format_round(int(t.get_text())))
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much @jezrael