# Editing seaborn heatmap annotations subject to value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is a heatmap via seaborn;

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df_heatmap, annot = True, cmap=cmap1, linewidths = 5, cbar = False, fmt=".3%", 
annot_kws = {"size": 12}, square = True)
```

Now, I want to set the annotations to one decimal place. I could do this via `fmt = ".1%"`, but then this sets many of the annotations to 0.0% (if they're less than 0.05%). This gives the appearance that there are no such occurrences of a given result but there is. Is there some way I can edit the annotations to include something like " < 0.1% " instead of 0.0%?

[image]

Comment: You probably need to create another dataframe where you set the values as you want (" < 0.1% " for values below 0.1) and pass it to the `annot` argument of the heatmap

Comment: Check this answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799642/13328010)